# JavaScript - How to increase all the element in int array by 1

Tags: javascript

How to increase all the element in an `int array` by `1`?

Ex: 
make `var a = [1,2,3,4]` and increase all elements inside so that the result gives

```
a = [2,3,4,5]
```

Is there any method except doing `a = a+[1,1,1,1]`?

Comment: `[1,2,3,4].map(n => n + 1)`.

Comment: doesn't map return a new array rather than altering the exisiting one?

Comment: He didn't specify this in the question, so I guess all solutions count unless he says otherwise.

Comment: a1 = []; a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; a.forEach(function(x){ a1.push(x + 1) }); console.log(a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, which will map each item within your array to a function that can be used to transform it:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(function(item) { 
    // Increment each item by 1
    return item + 1; 
});
```

**Example**

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(item) {
  return item + 1;
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays it is being done with the arrow functions as following :)

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4].map(v=> v+1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just use the JavaScript **map** function.

```
[1,2,3,4].map(function(entry) {
  return entry+1;
});
```

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

Another example of the **map** function in action provided by the MDN I added is;

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var doubles = numbers.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});

// doubles is now [2, 8, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map function

```
var a = [1,2,3,5];
var x = a.map(function(item){
   return item+1;

})
console.log(x)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/57cr6p7e/1/)