# How do I increment one value in an array?

Tags: angular

I have an array and it has a value `quantity`. And when I click on the button, the `quantity` should increase by 1 unit. At the moment, I have an increase for all values ​​of the `quantity` in the array by one. And how to do only for one?

ts:

```
  addItem() {
    this.order.list.forEach(o => {
      o.quantity = o.quantity + 1;
    })
  }
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of order.list">
    <span> {{item.quantity}}</span>
    <button class="my-fab" (click)="addItem()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - How to increase all the element in int array by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800616/javascript-how-to-increase-all-the-element-in-int-array-by-1)

Comment: You want to increase the quantity of _what_ single item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `map` instead of `forEach`

```
incrementAll() {
  this.order.list = this.order.list.map(o => ({...o, quantity: o.quantity + 1}))
}
```

and as for incrementing specific item's quantity, you must pass it's respective unique id/name to perform such condition where the button should be inside the `ngFor` loop per item:

```
incrementItem(id: number) {
  this.order.list = this.order.list.map(o => o.id === id ? {...o, quantity: o.quantity + 1} : o);
}
```

Here's the **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-87maiv?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference

Answer (score 0):

In template pass the item

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testOrder2.list">
   <strong>{{ item.product }}</strong>
   <p>{{ item.quantity }}</p>
  
     <button class="btn btn-primary" 
       (click)="incrementItem(item)">Increment</button>
   </div>
```

Since item passes by is always reference so following code will give a desired result

```
  incrementItem(item) {
    item.quantity++;  
  }
```

stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kjmbsn